# String parameter being interpreted as date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to pass a string parameter from Javascript to a controller method in a .NET MVC program, and it's interpreting it as a date somewhere along the way, and reformatted. I want it to stop, or at least get it right.

I have this line in a Javascript file:

```
window.open(viewUrl + "?fromDate=" + fromDates[pointIndex] + "&toDate=" + toDates[pointIndex]
```

A breakpoint in firebug tells me I have this:

[image: fromDates[pointIndex]]

But when it hits the controller it looks like this:

[image]

This would be all well and good except it's changed from October 1 to January 10 at some point between these. I can't rely on browser settings because it could be used in a number of countries/cultures, and it does the same thing if the `fromdates[pointIndex]` value is of the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

How can I get it to stop reformatting the string and just pass it through as it is in the Javascript array?

Comment: what is the signature of the action that handles the request?

Comment: It looks like this `public GridResult<TimesheetPivotedGridRow> GetAllTime(string fromDate, string toDate, GridDataFetchParams gridParams)`. The last param is being passed fine, the two strings are getting the reformatted dates

Answer (score 0):

The date is not changing Oct 1 to Jan 10 but the format is changing from "dd/MMM/yyyy" to "MM/DD/YYYY"

Try

```
fromDates[pointIndex].toString()
toDates[pointIndex].toString()
```

Or you can use a library like moment to pass it in a particular format